# How to get the stack trace from own methods only when using TPL?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to get the names of the methods so called my function, It seems a bit of a problem with Tpl

Is there any good solution?

BTW: I aware of the [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), But I want a different solution so will not clutter my code

Here is my test code so can break in the next version of the Tpl

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(F1().Result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task<string> F1()
    {
        return await F2();
    }

    static Task<string> F2()
    {
        var callingMethods = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Select(v => v.GetMethod().Name);
        var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, callingMethods);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

And this is the output

> F2
>
> MoveNext
>
> Start
>
> F1
>
> Main
>
> ...

Comment: Have you considered **why** it is a bit of a problem with TPL?

Comment: Because they put another layer between there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter out all assemblies that are not yours, for example by checking the assembly is not in the GAC:

```
var callingMethods = new StackTrace().GetFrames()
                         .Select(v => v.GetMethod())
                         .Where(m => !m.DeclaringType.Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache
                                     && !m.DeclaringType.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute))
                               )
                         .Select(m => m.Name);
```

Output:

> F2
>
> F1
>
> Main